# What are the differences between 'flutter run', 'flutter build', Start Debugging, Run Without Debugging, etc

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. There are different ways to run your app in Flutter. I am wondering what the differences are between these ways. I'm using Visual Studio Code on MacOS.

**Way 1**

> Visual Studio --> Run --> Start Debugging(^F5)

(Is there any command line equivalent of this? Knowing its command line equivalent will be helpful to make things more clear.)

**Way 2**

> Visual Studio --> Run --> Run Without Debugging(^F5)

(Is there any command line equivalent of this? Knowing its command line equivalent will be helpful to make things more clear.)

**Way 3**

command line --> `flutter run`

(Is it same with way 2?)

**Way 4**

command line --> `flutter run --release`
( I never used this command line, I always use Xcode traditional way to release my app)

**Way 5**

command line --> `flutter run --profile`

(I never used this command line, is it slow?)

**Way 6**

command line --> `flutter build <target>`

(I never used this command line, is it good or bad? Do you suggest?)

I never set breakpoints when I write code... I always use logging technique(`print()`) to develop my app.

Which way is the best for me? Which is the fastest? Pros & Cons?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Given the following [Flutter's build modes](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes):

**DEBUG MODE MEANS THAT:**

> - Assertions are enabled.
> - Service extensions are enabled.
> - Compilation is optimized for fast development and run cycles (but not for execution speed, binary size, or deployment).
> - Debugging is enabled, and tools supporting source-level debugging (such as DevTools) can connect to the process.
> - The build is not minified and tree shaking has not been performed (web only).
> - The app is compiled with the `dartdevc` compiler for easier debugging (web only).

**RELEASE MODE MEANS THAT:**

> - Assertions are disabled.
> - Debugging information is stripped out.
> - Debugging is disabled.
> - Compilation is optimized for fast startup, fast execution, and small package sizes.
> - Service extensions are disabled.
> - The build is minified and tree shaking has been performed (web only).
> - The app is compiled with the dart2js compiler for best performance (web only).

**PROFILE MODE MEANS THAT**

> - Some service extensions, such as the one that enables the performance overlay, are enabled.
> - Tracing is enabled, and tools supporting source-level debugging (such as DevTools) can connect to the process.
> - The build is not minified but tree shaking has been performed (web only).
> - The app is compiled with the dart2js compiler (web only).

So, to answer the question:

1. `Visual Studio --> Run --> Start Debugging(^F5)`

   This runs the app like `flutter run` but in debugging mode. I.e. breakpoints will pause the execution of the app if it reaches one of them.

   There is no command line equivalent for this one.
2. `Visual Studio --> Run --> Run Without Debugging(^F5)`

   The same as the 1st one but breakpoints are ignored. Equivalent to `flutter run`.
3. `command line --> flutter run`

   The same as the 2nd one
4. `command line --> flutter run --release`

   This runs the app in release mode. I.e. It ignores all asserts (strips them off the final app) and the global vars `kDebugMode` and `kReleaseMode` are `false` and `true` respectively.
5. `command line --> flutter run --profile`

   This includes performance profiling info in the built app. Generally, it makes the app slower than the other options.
6. `command line --> flutter build <target>`

   Builds the app for a specific target platform. It's good to use in a CI environment.

Breakpoints are superior as you can trigger them on a condition and even change values at runtime. But a mixture of them is pretty OK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Are you sure for 2 & 3? 
https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes "By default, 'flutter run' compiles to debug mode."

Comment: Yes. By default `flutter run` builds with debug info. But it's only possible to debug it if you attach the running app from a debugger like an IDE.

Comment: One more question... Which is the fastest for somebody who never use breakpoints? Is way2 is the best? In fact, way2 is faster than way1, I think. What are disadvantages of using way2? Additionally, way3 is not faster as way2 according to my experience, they should be different. My aim is to run my code as soon as possible. Final question, what is your way? Which way do you use when you develop apps?

Comment: The debug mode is optimized for fast building. This way it feels faster than building release mode but the app runs slower. On the other hand, in release mode, tree-shaking and optimization routines are executed to build an app that runs faster but builds slower. I think both 2 and 3 are good for developing but I generally go with 1 to break at specific points if I need to check or change some values on the go. Also, note that faster and slower are pretty relative. It depends on the kind of app you're developing.